# Pegar Rows do BD (MySQL) - WebService Mysql C#

Tags: c#, mysql, web-service

Estou tendo dificuldades para pegar as *rows*.

Ele não reconhece nenhuma variável dentro do `cmdMySQL` (`@Login`). Tentei colocar outras mas nada se eu tiro o `@Login` e coloco o o valor de `email` que esteja no BD ele acha normalmente.

Meu código:

```
[WebMethod]
public int connectoToMySql()
{
    string Login = "emaildeteste";
    string Pass = "umasenhaforteai";

    string connString = "SERVER=local" + ";" +
        "DATABASE=admin;" +
        "UID=root;" +
        "PASSWORD=*******;" +
        "Allow User Variables = True;";

    MySqlConnection cnMySQL = new MySqlConnection(connString);

    MySqlCommand cmdMySQL = cnMySQL.CreateCommand();

    MySqlDataReader reader;

    cmdMySQL.CommandText = "select * from core_members where `email` = @Login";

    cnMySQL.Open();

    reader = cmdMySQL.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);

    cnMySQL.Close();

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        return 1;
        Console.WriteLine("Pegou a ROW");
    }
    return 50; //so testando
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltou passar **o valor do parâmetro `@Login`** para a *query*.

Ficaria dessa forma:

```
cmdMySQL.CommandText = "select * from core_members where `email` = @Login";
cmdMySQL.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Login", Login );
```

Um adendo: a variável `Login`, segundo a [guia de nomenclatura do C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xzf533w0(v=vs.71).aspx), 
deveria ser `login`.